# how to count dynamically added table rows

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript

My table has already 5 rows...after pressing addrow, rows are added dynamically to another table... I need to save the data of all the rows(5+newly added) in the database...

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Read *all* the faq (http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Comment: by "rows are added dynamically", do you mean they are added by JavaScript?  or through code-behind during a postback?  It'd help if you posted some code.

Comment: Is this a DataTable? An HTML table? GridView / ListView / etc.? Need more detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `DataAdapter` + `DataTable.AcceptChanges()`.

Answer (score 0):

You create a new variable that stores the current amount of tables and then increase it in the same action when a new table is created... shouldn't be too hard ;)